# PHP Javascript Ajax window.location Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, location

There is software that uses Ajax Get. The code below does not work. What can I do?

Javascript code:

```
    <script>
        function buy_product(cid) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/buyProduct/' + cid,
                type: 'get',
                success: function(response) {
                    var result = $.parseJSON(response);
                    if (result["success"]) {
                        iziToast.success({
                            theme: 'dark',
                            message: result["message"],
                            timeout: 3000
                        }).then(function() {
                            window.location = "/my/products";
                        }, 3000);
                    } else {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, err) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Example response:

```
{"success":true,"message":"Success","status":"SUCCESS"}
```

Console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
```

If it output is success, "iziToast.success" is running. But window.location is not working.

Comment: It kind of sounds like `iziToast.success` doesn't return a Promise

Comment: I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onClosed` option to specify a function that should be called when the user closes the dialog.

```
                        iziToast.success({
                            theme: 'dark',
                            message: result["message"],
                            timeout: 3000.
                            onClosed: function() {
                                window.location = "/my/products";
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    var redirectFunc = function() {
                        window.location = "/my/products";
                    };
                    iziToast.success({
                        theme: 'dark',
                        message: result["message"],
                        timeout: 3000
                    });
                    setTimeout(redirectFunc, 3000);
```

This is how I solved the problem.

Comment: I'm not an expert on iziToast, but it seems like there's an onClosed event you could use: `iziToast.success({theme: 'dark', message: result["message"], timeout: 3000,
onClosed: redirectFunc});`